# Assigning derived class object to a parent class reference

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am always puzzled when I see:

```
Parent ref = new Child();
```

where Child class extends Parent.

1. How does the object `ref` look like in memory?
2. How is virtual method treated? non-virtual?
3. How is it different from:

```
Child ref = new Child();
```

Comment: I hope not, I hate it when I get tricked into answering homework. I took his word for why he was asking; maybe I should get rid of my answer...

Comment: I guess give the OP the benefit of the doubt eh?

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - I say absolutely.  If he's cheating on homework, and I'm **not** saying he is, then so much the worse for him come final exam time.  In any event, the question is clear, intelligent, and provides good content for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not homework. I am a working professional. I've been asked that question in interview and has been puzzled since.

Comment: Try to not use 'ref' -- it is a keyword.

Answer (score 7):

> How does the object look in memory?

Your question is unclear. There are two relevant memory locations. The *variable* is associated with a storage location. That storage location contains a *reference* to *another* storage location.

The variable's storage location is typically realized as a four or eight byte integer that contains a "managed pointer" -- a memory address known to the garbage collector.

The object's memory layout is also an implementation detail of the CLR. The memory buffer associated with the object will contain all the data for the object -- all the values of the fields and whatnot. It also contains a reference to yet *another* memory location, the *virtual function table* of the object.

The virtual function table (vtable) then contains *even more references*, this time references that refer to the methods associated with the most-derived type of the object.

> How is virtual method treated? non-virtual?

Virtual methods are executed by looking up the object reference from the variable, then looking up the vtable, then looking up the method in the vtable, and then invoking that method.

Non-virtual methods are not invoked via the vtable because they are known at compile time.

> How is it different from...

Non-virtual methods called on the object will call the version of the method based on the type of the *variable*. Virtual methods called on the object will call the version of the method based on the type of the *object* that the variable refers to.

If that is not all clear, you might want to read my article that explains how you might "emulate" virtual methods in a language that does not have them. If you can understand how to implement virtual methods yourself in a language that does not have them, that will help you understand how we actually *do* implement virtual methods.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`ref` is a `Child` object. virtual methods are called on `Child` class. However, methods defined only in `Child` class are not visible when assigned to `Parent` object.

If `foo()` was not virtual, then the compile will select a method based on the declared type of the variable `ref`. If you have `Parent ref = new Child();` then `Parent.foo()` will be called. If you have `Child ref = new Child();` then `Child.foo()` will be called. Of course, in this case the C# compiler will ask you to use `new` in the declaration of `Child.foo()` to indicate that you mean to hide the implementation in `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine `ref` just contains the address where the referred-to `Child` object can be found. If you call a virtual method, the actual method invoked depends on the dynamic type of the object (`Child`); if you call a non-virtual method, it depends on the static type (`Parent`). It's different from `Child ref = ...` because in that one, the static type is `Child` rather than `Parent`.

And I hope this isn't homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way  (assuming Parent is not an abstract class)

```
Parent ref = new Child();
```

and

```
Parent ref = new Parent();
```

Are mostly the same, except **virtual** methods overridden in Child will be called in the former, but not the latter.

The **type** that you declare the object as will determine which methods are **available** on it.  Declaring an object to be a less specific type than what you instantiate it as—the former case—*can* affect which methods get called at **runtime**, but only if those methods are declared as abstract or virtual.

In either case, imagine you called a method `foo` on ref.  The runtime would fine method `foo` on class `Parent`.  The runtime would then see if `foo` was virtual (or abstract).  If `foo` was not virtual or abstract, the runtime would call the `foo` Parent defines right then and there, and be done with it.  If however `foo` *were* virtual or abstract, the runtime would check to see if ref were *really* instantiated to a more specific type that overrode `foo`.  If so, it would call *that* `foo`

Comment: if foo exists as non-virtual methods both in Parent and Child class, and ref.foo() is called. Which one is called?

Comment: The method will be called based on the type of `ref`. if you have `Parent ref = new Child();` then `Parent.foo()` will be called. If you have `Child ref = new Child();` then `Child.foo()` will be called. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: @TingYun - I couldn't have said it any clearer that drdwilcox did