# Base Class = New Derived Class. How does this work?

Tags: c#, class

Say I have a base class called Enemy and a derived class called Ogre.

What is the difference between creating an instance these two ways:

```
Enemy newOgre = new Ogre();

Ogre newOgre = new Ogre();
```

Comment: better use `IEnemy` interface rather than `Enemy` base class. If you won't create new Enemies as base class, interface will be more suitable

Comment: There are no much diffesence between this creations, exept new object with refefence of Enemy type will only provide base class interface.

Comment: You're *not* creating them differently.  You're doing something different with the objects that you're creating identically (namely storing them in a different way).

Comment: What do you want to know? How it works under the hood (e.g. how virtual methods are found -- search for v-table lookup)? Or how to use it (search for inheritance)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning derived class object to a parent class reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390945/assigning-derived-class-object-to-a-parent-class-reference)

Answer (score 16):

Actually, the piece of code that is creating the instance is only `new Ogre()`. What is in the left side of the equal sign has nothing to do with creating the instance.

The first statement is simply assigning the created instance to a variable of type `Enemy`. The second one is assigning it to a variable of type `Ogre`.

So you have two **variables** of different types pointing to objects of the **same** type, i.e. `Ogre`.

The variable (what is on the **left side** of the equal sign), only determines what you can access from the object. For example, if the `Ogre` class has a method that is not inherited from `Enemy`, then using the `Enemy` variable, you will not be able to access it.

Please note that the variable does not effect how the object behave. For example, if `Ogre` overrides a method defined in `Enemy` that does something different. Calling this method on an instance of `Ogre` using a variable of type `Enemy` would cause the overridden method in `Ogre` to be invoked, not the one in `Enemy`,

For example, consider these classes:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enemy");
    }
}

public class Ogre: Enemy
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ogre");
    }
}
```

Now if you do this:

```
Orge enemy = new Orge();
enemy.Test();
```

The console would print "ogre".

And if you do this:

```
Enemy enemy = new Ogre();
enemy.Test();
```

The console would still print "orge".

Comment: I feel you should also mention that if you are hiding a method in `Ogre` and assign an `Ogre` to an `Enemy` variable, calling the method with the `Enemy` variable will call the base method, not the hidden one.

Comment: Typically, that is the desired behavior in inheritance hierarchies. You want objects that have values that are created from the derived class to use the methods that are defined in the derived class. You achieve that behavior by using override to extend the base class method.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Yacoub's answer, in this case, Enemy would not contain the properties, and methods that Ogre has.

```
public class Enemy
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Ogre : Enemy
{
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say you inherit Enemy in your Ogre class. This mean that your Ogre will effectively contain 3 properties: 1,2 and 3.

In your example you're assigning an `Ogre` to an `Enemy` type.
The Enemy type doesn't contain a "Property3" and therefor you won't be able to work with the extended class "`Ogre`" in an `Enemy` cast object.

```
//This will work
Ogre newOgre = new Ogre();
int newInt = newOgre.Property3;

//This wont.
Enemy newOgre = new Ogre();
int newInt = newOgre.Property3;
```

Answer (score 3):

One declares a *variable* of type `Enemy` and references a new `Ogre` object.  The other declares a variable of type `Ogre` and references a new `Ogre` object.

Some differences (not an exhaustive list):

- You can't call non-inherited methods of `Ogre` on the variable of type `Enemy`.
- Any virtual methods of `Enemy` that are overridden in `Ogre` will use `Ogre's` implementation when called on either variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your Enemy class looks like this:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public void Attack() { }
    public void Move() { }
}
```

and your Ogre class like this:

```
public class Ogre : Enemy
{
    public void OgreSmash() { }
}
```

With the Enemy variable you would only have access to `Attack()` and `Move()` but not to the `OgreSmash()` with the Ogre variable you will have access to the methods of the base and derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
Enemy newOgre = new Ogre();
```

you can't call method using `newOgre` that was later added to the class `Ogre` for example and was not in the base class, whereas using the other variable you can call those methods.